# tfs 2010 how to prevent lock when check in

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I installed the tfs 2010 in the my pc where I use VS2010 ultimate,
all my project group can chek-in without probleme (with the user icon) except me; when I check in the file will be locked (lock icon) !!

My files in project:

[image]

other pcs files :

[image]

Comment: which file type? posting a screenshot would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'lock' that is shown in your first picture simply means that this file `MainPanel.cs` is checked in.
Any other user should be able to check this out for edit.
What you are showing in the second picture tells us that `MainPanel.cs`, along with all other files, is checked-out by another user. My guess is that there is simply another developer who has `MainPanel.cs` checked out.
In order to find out who has what checked-out: Install latest [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963), part of it is "Team Members".
[image]
 You can add there any Valid Team Project user and investigate her/his checkouts with "Show Pending Changes" :
[image].
Another note that might be relevant to your question:
When you select to check out any file, it's possible to select out of three different lock types that influence what other devs can do with the sources you have checked out:
[image]

Comment: thx for the reply, but my friend when he make check in he got the user icon but when i make chek in I got lock icon, anf the seconf probleme I have all file with yes notification (I can't know what file was modified by me )

Comment: The "User" icon means that another Developer had checked out this file (probably You). If you hover with the mouse over the icon in Solution Explorer you will get a popup saying that this file is "Checked out by someone else or in another place". If no other Developer has checked out the file, you will get a "Lock" icon - which means that the file is checked in by everyone (hover says "Checked In").